# Watcher exclude specific folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code 1.47.3, and can't find how to exclude myproject/data from the watcher. I can exclude all of them, using **/data, as can be seen in the default configuration:

[image]

If I also have myproject/stuff/data, and don't want it to be excluded, what can I do?